# Ranking System: How Does it Work?

Tags: rocket-league

How does the ranking system work in Rocket League currently?

It seems that I when I win 9 or 10 games in a row and then lose 1, my ranking remains the same. I'm currently Challenger Rank 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost all of these systems used in game for ranking are based on an ELO formula (see [elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)) - it comes from chess.

The basics of it are this: if you are seriously outmatched and lose, you lose 1 point, if you are seriously outmatched and win, you gain 32 points. If you are even and lose, you lose 16 points. If you are even and win you gain 16 points.

There are various shades in there ranging from 1-32 points, but hopefully you get the point. If you win 8 games against easy opponents you may only gain several points, however if on the ninth you lose to an easier opponent (by ranking) then you can easily negate your 8 wins, or at least most of those points.

If I had to **guess**, it would look something like this

- 900: Prospect I
- 1000: Prospect II
- 1100: Prospect III
- 1200: Prospect Elite
- 1300: Challenger I
- 1400: Challenger II
- 1500: Challenger III
- 1600: Challenger Elite
- 1700: Rising Star
- 1800: Shooting Star
- 1900: All-Star
- 2000: Superstar
- 2200: Champion
- 2400: Super Champion
- 2600: Grand Champion

Comment: How many points equates a Rank in RL, though?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't really a good way to tell that, @Will. As Rocket League only displays a named rank instead of the numeric value, we can only guess. Usually the range in an ELO system will go from 1000 points to 3000 points, give or take depending on the variety of players. So, we could make estimates given that distribution. Perhaps something along the lines of 100 points per rank, where most players probably leave unranked at a rating of 1400. I edited in a very rough guess.

Comment: @Travisj - Thanks for explaining the ELO system, very helpful.

Comment: Also are you sure you are actually winning that many games in a row? I find it hard to believe you won 9-10 straight and barely progressed in rankings. I was ranked Prospect Elite at the beginning of a season, and after going an average of 2 wins to every loss, I was up to Challenger III within a day or two.

Answer (score -4):

Rocket League Ranked works in a way to prevent getting dragged to higher ranks.
To constantly get up, you constantly have to be the best of your team (hence proof that you are better than your rank) This usually starts at Challenger 3.