# How do win/losses count toward ranking up or down?

Tags: rocket-league

I was under the opinion that one win will always cause you to rank up (provide you have enough wins to be ranked in the first place) and that one loss will always cause you to rank down.  But I was just in a 3v2 rumble game (I was on the 2) and against all odds my outnumbered team won.  I did not rank up or down, my rank stayed the same.

Am I wrong on how ranking works?  I realize this has been asked before, but a lot of the questions are outdated, and it's hard to know what changes have been made since Epic Games acquire the game.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ranking System: How Does it Work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302296/ranking-system-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Agree that's a dupe for this, but it's due for an update since RL has updated their system

Comment: Since the other question doesn't answer me, I created a new one as instructed  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387864/update-on-how-rocket-leagues-ranking-system-works

Comment: the other question is 4 years old, so it's too outdated.

Comment: @n_plum when did RL update their system?

Comment: https://support.rocketleague.com/hc/en-us/articles/360054049854-What-Are-Competitive-Ranks- there are way more ranks now than are listed on that older answer